# Fetch SQLite single cell and display in single TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

ANSWER: Please note that I used a combination of both suggestions to produce the following code:

DBAdapter.java:

```
String name = "";

public String getName(long l) {
    Cursor result = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
            DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, //Name of your table
            new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME }, //List of columns to return, as a String array. Just one in your case.
            DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "=?", //The row selection criteria. Equivalent to saying "Where the key id is equal to..."
            new String[] { String.valueOf(l) }, //...this value
            null, //This parameter deals with grouping results. No need here, hence null.
            null, //Relates to the above. Also null.
            null //Orders results. There should just be one, so it's null here, but can be useful.
    );

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
    }
    return name;
```

CharacterInfo.java (NavigationDrawer Parent):

```
DBAdapter myDb = new DBAdapter(this);

myDb.open();
String name = myDb.getName(1);
mTitle1 = name;
myDb.close();
```

While this produced an error free environment, the app crashes due to a `"No such table"` error `(code 1)` which I have yet to solve.

END ANSWER

Firstly, I know there are a lot of these types of questions. I've looked at at least a dozen and can't seem to wrap my head around it, so I'm posting a question in hopes that someone can do me a favor and explain it to me in greater detail along with providing the method.

I want to create a method that fetches the `KEY_NAME` for the `KEY_ROWID` that I specify. (I think this can be done using the `getRow()` method that's already in `DBAdapter`). Then, turn that into a string in order to display it a `TextView`.

I need to know how to fill out the method at the bottom of `DBAdapter` named `getName`

A perfect answer would allow me to write the following code in a separate activity setting the title: `mTitle1 = getName;`

Thank you all so much for your time.

I have a really nice `DBAdapter` provided by a tutorial that I followed:

```
public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbCharacters";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Character_Info";
// The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT"
        + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String name, String date) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String date) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}

public void getName (long id) {

}

}
```

Here's PPartisan's Suggestion:

```
public String getName(long l) {
    Cursor result = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
            DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, //Name of your database
            new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME }, //List of columns to return, as a String array. Just one in your case.
            DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "=?", //The row selection criteria. Equivalent to saying "Where the key id is equal to..."
            new String[] { String.valueOf(1) }, //...this value
            null, //This parameter deals with grouping results. No need here, hence null.
            null, //Relates to the above. Also null.
            null //Orders results. There should just be one, so it's null here, but can be useful.
    );

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
    }
    return name;
```

Zahan's Suggestion:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.character_info);

    mCharacterInfoDrawerFragment = (CharacterInfo_Drawer_Fragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    openDB();
    String name = DBAdapter.getName(1);
    mTitle1 = name;
    closeDB();


    mCharacterInfoDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving data from an `SQLite` database in Android involves running a query, ideally (IMO) with the [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method (you can also use `rawQuery()`).

As database operations can easily run for a long time (several seconds) you want to query your database as few times as possible, make the query itself as specific as you can and really conduct it off the UI thread.

If, for instance, you truly only want to access one "cell" of your database, then you would construct a `query()` as follows:

```
Cursor result = myDbInstance.getReadableDatabase().query(
    DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE, //Name of your table
    new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME }, //List of columns to return, as a String array. Just one in your case.
    DBAdapter.KEY_ID + "=?", //The row selection criteria. Equivalent to saying "Where the key id is equal to..."
    new String[] { String.valueOf(idOfTheRowToQuery) }, //...this value
    null, //This parameter deals with grouping results. No need here, hence null.
    null, //Relates to the above. Also null.
    null //Orders results. There should just be one, so it's null here, but can be useful.
    )
```

All of this will return a `Cursor` object. To access the `String` stored, you would check to see whether it has an entry (which it should), move to the first (and only, in this case) entry, and run the following:

```
if (result.moveToFirst()) {
    String name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
}
```

Then you just assign it to your `TextView`.

A few points to keep in mind though:

1. It's often recommended to use a `static synchronized singleton` with your database instance. Look [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html) for more info.
2. If you truly only need one entry, then the above is fine. However, if you are likely to need more, then you should structure your `query()` in such a way that it returns everything you need and nothing more in as few passes as possible, for performance reasons.
3. Database operations are slow, and should be conducted off the UI thread. Often this is done with `AsyncTask`, but it isn't the only method by any means. I made a blog post that goes over a lot of these points [here](http://partisanapps.com/2015/08/really-useful-notes-saving-and-loading-with-a-local-database-i/) if you're interested.

Comment: Hey, there's an error of `"Cannot resolve symbol of 'KEY_NAME'"` in the `if statement`. I posted the added code into the OP.

Comment: @Mikitz06 Oh, sorry, that should be `DBAdapter.KEY_NAME` - I'll change it now.

Comment: results in `"Cannot resolver symbol 'DBAdapter'"` Also, it says there's a missing `return statement`. Should it be `return name;` ?

Comment: `DBAdapter` is the name of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class isn't it? It is in your OP - P.s. And yes, in the way you've implemented it into your question, `name` would be the `String` you return.

Comment: I just saw your edit. All is working now except for the missing return statement on the closing curly bracket for the method.

Comment: The `return` statement in your method would be `name`.

Comment: adding `return name;` results in `"Cannot resolve symbol name"` error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92905/discussion-between-ppartisan-and-mikitz06).

Comment: Just for those that come here looking for help, there's a typo: `DATABASE_NAME` should actually be `DATABASE_TABLE_NAME` otherwise you'll get a `no such table` error thrown

Comment: You're right - the first paramater is for the table name, not the database name. In your OP this is stored under the constant `DATABASE_TABLE` in your `DBAdapter` class, but it can be anything so long as it holds the right `String` value :). I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm struggling with your tut here: `http://partisanapps.com/2015/08/really-useful-notes-saving-and-loading-with-a-local-database-ii/` Wondering if I could ask you a few questions in chat or via email?

Comment: @Mikitz06 Sure - send me an email or leave a comment  on the page :). Email's on my profile page.

Answer (score 1):

Create method `getName` like below

```
public String getName(long l)
{
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_ROWID};
    Cursor c=yourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME,columns,KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null,null,null,null);
   if(c!=null)
   {
   c.moveToFirst();
   String name=c.getString(1);   // use your desired column's index instead of 1
   return name;
   }
return null;
}
```

Now you can call from your activity  and set TextView likelike

```
Your_db_class object_name=new Your_db_class();
object_name.open();    
String mTitle1 = object_name.getName(1);  //KEY_ROWID
object_name.close();
textView.setText(""+mTitle1+"");
```

Comment: On `return name;` error of `"Incompatible types. Required: string - Found: java.lang.String"`

Comment: It should be okey now. i just did case mistake. code is okey.try now @Mikitz06

Comment: Coded added to OP. Results in error over `getName` showing `"Non-static method 'getName(long)' cannot be referenced from a static context"` I'm trying to set the ActionBar title within a NavigationDrawer parent activity.

Comment: Still throwing the same error. See updated code in the OP, please :)